# Visual Code keyboard shortcut - jump past brace

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have searched the Visual Code documentation but cannot find the answer.

When typing in a Javascript file and tapping open brace {  .. Visual Code inserts the closing brace }

Is there a shortcut key to automatically accept that closing brace and jump to the next line.

Currently having to use arrow key to get to end of line and pressing return.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

Comment: Won't just downarrow work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on windows and have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> bound to jump to the end of the line for this exact purpose. If you just want to make a new line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.